# Fail2Ban banning addresses that SHOULD already be banned

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, fail2ban

I am running the default fail2ban ssh-auth rule to ban ips with 3 or more failed auth attempts in a window. However, I noticed a particular network being the source of a disproportionate amount of abusive traffic, so I decided to completely drop all traffic from them to receive fewer alerts and potentially improve the signal-to-noise ratio. To that end, I added the following IPTABLES rules:

```
-A INPUT -s 107.189.0.0/19 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-11 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 209.141.32.0/19 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-04 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 205.185.112.0/20 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-03 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
```

However, I am still receiving MANY alerts daily from fail2ban informing me that it has banned addresses from the above network. I can't for the life of me understand why that might be; since I would expect to only see bans happening to addresses that can actually contact my server. Why is this happening?

Below is the entire iptables rulechain, with some blocks removed for privacy

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-N f2b-wordpress-hard
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-wordpress-hard
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -s 107.189.0.0/19 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-11 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 209.141.32.0/19 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-04 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 205.185.112.0/20 -m comment --comment "PONYNET-03 / FranTech Solutions (SYNDI-5)" -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
[... some number of rejected ips ...]
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-wordpress-hard -j RETURN
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Apache%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You are appending your rules. They probably end up placed after your fail2ban chain and other rules allowing ssh and therefore are ineffective. Show us full iptables-save output for analysis.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good point. I'll update the Question with a redacted chain from one of the servers

Comment: I believe that's exactly what is happening. Traffic to PORTS 80, 443, and 22 are jumping to the corresponding f2b rules, and the blocks are never being evaluated.

I'll answer my own question after testing for a solution if someone else hasn't written up an answer by then

Comment: You have ssh ratelimiting in ufw-user-input chain which may be allowing the traffic before it reaches your denial rules. Have a look there. And consider dropping firewall helpers, they tend to overcomplicate and obfuscate the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment from Tomek, I realized that I was appending to the INPUT chain with ansible, instead of inserting new rules to the beginning.

Once I inserted the rules then I got the the expected behavior.